# Why doesnt this operator usage in the trailing return type compile?

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-keyword, language-lawyer, trailing-return-type

I was trying to reuse the return type of an operator in my trailing return type of another function, but unfortunately clang did not accept it

```
struct A {
  int operator[](int);
  auto at(int i) -> decltype((*this)[i]);
};
```

Clang says that my class does not have a operator[]. Gcc did accept my code. Is my code actually invalid?

Comment: Clang should be right, `this` isn't available at the point of declaration of the member function, it's only available inside a member function. (§9.3.2/1 "In the body of a non-static (9.3) member function, the keyword `this` is a prvalue expression [...]").

Comment: @xeo i disagree. as a last minute change, the committee in madrid made using this inside a trailing return type valid to facilitate inheriting the constness of the enclosing member function.

Comment: If clang says there is no `operator[](int)`, it's obviously wrong. So what's the question? The issue regarding the validity of using `this` here is a *different* one. I agree with Johannes that it must be valid here.

Comment: So, the question really is : can you use `this` in decltype for the return of the method?

Comment: @Bjo no my question is whether this code is valid or not. clang accepts using "this" in trailing return types in general, so i am not sure what i should ask more precisely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say that clang is correct, due to 13.3.1.2p3 (1st bullet).

> For a unary operator `@` with an operand of a type whose cv-unqualified version is `T1`, and for a binary
>   operator `@` with a left operand of a type whose cv-unqualified version is `T1` and a right operand of a type
>   whose cv-unqualified version is `T2`, three sets of candidate functions, designated member candidates, nonmember
>   candidates and built-in candidates, are constructed as follows:
>
> - If `T1` is a complete class type, the set of member candidates is the result of the qualified lookup of
>     `T1::operator@` (13.3.1.1.1); otherwise, ***the set of member candidates is empty***.

(emphasis added by @sehe)

Comment: -1: For being wrong. p3 does not apply to `operator[]`. p3 pertains only to operators of the form `@a`, where `@` is a unary operator. operator[] is not; it's governed by a separate section.

Comment: Hyperlink only answers are bad. You seem to have taken it to a whole new level! This link is broken by design. Could you at least _quote_ the relevant text?

Comment: @Nicol Bolas Quite so. I completely missed that [] was handled by another section. Thanks for putting me straight.

Comment: @nicol i disagree. operator[] is a binary operator where @ is [] IMHO. the bullet for builtins for example mentions also operator->.

Comment: So, is class 'A' considered to be incomplete at the declaration of 'at' in the OP? ($9.2/2)

Comment: @Chubsdad yes, that is mandatory because otherwise the type of class member functions in a class would only be partially known (it would have a placeholder return type). the committee did not want to have such beasts.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: "*i disagree. operator[] is a binary operator where @ is [] IMHO.*" It doesn't matter what your opinion is; the spec is very clear. That section is very clear: operator[] is covered by a different section of the spec than regular binary operators. Binary operators are covered by 13.5.2; the subscript operator is covered by 13.5.5. So as far as this part of the spec is concerned, it is a completely different matter.

Comment: @nicol i can *only* express opinions. the question is how found these are. in this case i think you are confusing paragraphs of 13.5, which are describing operator functions (functions that implement operator semantics), with the referred 13.3.1.2p3, which describe how the use of an operator syntax can result in a call to an operator function or builtin operator. in that paragraph, operator[] is an ordinary binary operator because it has two operands and two operand types.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: 13.3.1.2p2 clearly says, "where @ denotes one of the operators covered in the specified subclause". The "specified subclause" for "binary operator" is *different* from the "specific subclause" for `operator[]`. I don't see how you can interpret `operator[]` as a binary operator in this case.

Comment: @nicol you are one paragraph before the one we are referring to. the table you are at just enumerates the operator syntax with the corresponding mapping to the operator function. and in fact the operator function specification for operator[] is in a different section than for the other binary operators. but how would that affect the paragraphs and what they apply to at 13.3?

Comment: @nicol and it all makes a great deal of sense. the operator function for operator[] is only allowed to be a member, which makes it different than other binary operators. but operator[] too needs overload resolution because operator functions can compete with builtin operators for carrying out the semantics of a use of []. 13.3.1.2p3 does not exclude operator[] when it refers to "binary operator", and that wouldnt make any sense either.

Comment: @nicol the source of confusion is the use of "@" in both paragraphs. but clearly the use in p3 is not intended to match up with the set of uses in p2. for instance p3 special cases operator->, which isnt pattern matched by p2 either.

Answer (score 3):

It seems, that it's CLang's bug, because the next code

```
struct A {
  int operator[](int);
  auto at(int i) -> decltype( this-> operator[]( i ) );
};
```

compiles by CLang as well - http://liveworkspace.org/code/2Myghk$6

Comment: That may be, but this isn't proof.

Comment: someone said to me tonight that it is not a clang bug, but i cannot remember the reason :-( can you please show a conclusive trace of paragraphs that prove that clangs behavior is wrong?

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Did they say why it isn't a clang bug? :)

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb You ask a sentence proving the behaviour of CLang is wrong.... well I cannot... but I find you asking really much when **At least the error message of Clang is plain all wrong**: I obviously see a operator [] in your class.

Comment: Honestly, I don't know is CLang right or wrong in this particular case, but if it can work with the form `(*this).operator[]( i )` and can't work with the form `(*this)[ i ]` - this is IMHO a bug

Answer (score 2):

just to re-iterate mine and Stephane's comment:

**This is an obvious bug in clang**, since your class obviously has an `operator[](int)`.

Whether or not the code using `decltype()` is valid, is a subtly different question
(I would say it is valid, but cannot prove it).

Comment: i reworded the question. i am not really interested in whether the wording of the error message is actually OK. i am more interested whether my code is valid C++ or not. i am sorry if my wording caused confusion.

Comment: many invalid c++ code will trigger nonsensical error messages, by the way :-) some of the more prominent candidates is when you forget a typename somewhere.